# Sorting a matrix by value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I translated a grayscale picture into a matrix that contains the intensity values of each pixel as integers. Now I'm looking for a way to sort the matrix by its pixel intensity values. Take the following matrix for example:

[image]

The output should be:

[image]

I couldn't get the desired result using `numpy.sort`, does anyone have an idea how to do this?

**EDIT:** Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Pillow library, to manipulate images
from PIL import Image

# reading image with PIL module
original = Image.open('original_reduced.png')

# converting it to a numpy array. numpy arrays are easier to manipulate 
im_original = np.array(original)

#plt.imshow(im_original, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)

# size of full image
im_original.shape

## size and cropping coordinates
s = 170
x, y = 85, 85

# crops image of his face
im = im_original[y:y+s, x:x+s]


## im_b should be "im" sorted
im_b = ???

#print(im)
#print(im_b)

plt.imshow(im_b, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please share some example code of what you tried, including some sample data (could be in the code), so people can see what you're actually working on. (the reason to ask is that writing a trivial example using your images of data actually simply works with `numpy.sort` - so it's impossible to say why it doesn't for you, without seeing how you tried coding it)

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Need to convert it back to an image using PIL `Image.fromarray(sorted_image)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the flattened array and `reshape` to original shape in Fortran-like order:

```
np.sort(a.ravel()).reshape(a.shape, order='F')
```

input:

```
a = np.array([[4,2,1,3],
              [6,5,7,8],
              [11,10,9,12]
             ])
```

output:

```
array([[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12]])
```

Comment: I'd use `ravel()` instead of `flatten()` since a copy is not really needed at that point.